# How can I identify whether it is local or global ambiguity?

Tags: ambiguity, sentences, word-sense-disambiguation, complex-sentences

I am currently learning about local and global ambiguity and we had the following example in of the texts explaining what the topic is about:

**Paul sent the note to Elena.**

**Paul sent the books, a record, some letters and the note to Elena.**

So for me the ambiguity lies in the possibility that it could either mean that Paul sent a note to Elena, or that he sent a note to Elena, to someone. Both the sentences seem alike to me and my guess was that it is local ambiguity but I cannot seem to find out how I can "solve" the sentence and if I should use the serial or parallel strategy to solve it.

This is quite confusing to me and I don't understand it so some help would be much appreciated.

Leonard